# Size of Beamer Button

Tags: beamer, size, button

How can I manually set the size of each beamer button? If I have two or more buttons on the same slide I would like that these buttons have the same size. So even if the number of letters in each button is different the size should be the same and the words should be centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure that all your texts have the same length, e.g. by using `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \beamergotobutton{\makebox[3cm]{very long text}}
  
  \beamergotobutton{\makebox[3cm]{shorty}}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]